# Insert multiple Pictures from Folder in descending order

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I insert a number of pictures from a Folder. The program is supposed to start at the top of the folder and insert the pictures in a descending order, but it does not.

The very first 3-5 pictures come last in the presentation, while all others are in perfect order.

```
Sub createTransModel()

    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oPicture As Shape
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myFolder As String
    Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim rotSlide As Slide

    Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
    myFolder = GetFolderPath()
    myFile = Dir(myFolder & "*.png")

    Do While myFile <> ""
        Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, _
        ppLayoutBlank)
        Set oPicture = oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(myFile, _
          msoFalse, msoTrue, 1, 1, _
          ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth, _
          ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight)

        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    fileName = inputBox("Please enter the filename")
    ActivePresentation.SaveAs (fileName & ".pps")
End Sub


Public Function GetFolderPath() As String


    Dim myFile As Object
    Dim fileSelected As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim objPPT As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim folderFromPath As String
    Dim directory As String

    directory = "M:\tm\public\Conti_Anlage\Voith Proben"

    Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With myFile
        .InitialFileName = directory
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Function
        End If
        fileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With


    For i = Len(fileSelected) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(fileSelected, i, 1) = "\" Then
            folderFromPath = Left(fileSelected, i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    GetFolderPath = folderFromPath

End Function
```

Comment: If it's the first and the last that you selected that are swapped, that might be because the windows explorer that is used in the file dialog swaps them (an old bug they can't correct anymore because of too many workarounds). Just swap the first and last items in the list in that case.

Comment: I had that bug too, but fixed it already. Though its not in the code i posted. The bug seems to be independant from that one

Comment: No, I see, that's not your problem here, you are looping through the files manually and don't select multiple in the file dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things here 
1. To resolve your order issue, you could get all the files in the folder (i.e. use a 'For' loop: `For Each oFile in oMyFolder.Files`) and then order them the way you want them (maybe in an array). Now you can add them.
2. Your 'GetFolderPath' function: from what I can see, you want the user to select a file and then you are returning the folder of the selected file. You could just use '`Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`'. This will ask the user to select a folder. This way you don't have to worry about extracting the folder. If you still want to get the folder of the selected file, have a look at '[File System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx)' object. You could use that to get the folder (i.e. `filesystemobject.GetParentFolderName(MyFile)`)

Answer (score 0):

The order of files that you see in a Windows file explorer window depends on your file explorer settings.  Files might be displayed alphabetically by name, in size order or sorted in various other ways.  That's file explorer's doing and has nothing to do with the actual order in which the files appear on the disk.

Dir$ when called repeatedly gives you the files in the order  in which they appear on the disk. If you want them in a particular order, you'll have to sort them or perhaps copy them into a folder in the order you want them to be returned by Dir.